# SQLalchemy missing sqlite dialect, how do I add it?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I made a project on a computer with SQLAlchemy working fine, but copied it over to my main one, and now I get the error "can't load plugin: SQLAlchemy.dialects.sqLite". I believe it may be missing sqlite. Is there any way I can add the plugin, or at least view where it should be?

Comment: More than likely an issue with your Python environment. Are you using virtualenv? Or something else.

Comment: I am not using virtualenv. An issue with python environment sounds like it may be the cause. will investigate.